# Maven project issues when parent pom is inside a folder in root project directory

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module maven project in which there is a pom.xml(1) file in the root project directory which specifies another pom.xml(2) file as its parent pom which is inside a folder in the root project directory.

Ideally, pom.xml(1) should be the parent pom but I don't know why we have another pox.xml(2) as its parent.

Project structure is like this-

```
project-name(root)
 ---module 1
 ---module 2
 ---folder
    --pom.xml(2) (parent pom)
 ---module 3
 --pom.xml(1) (this pom should have been the parent pom but it specifies pom.xml(2) as it's parent)
```

Now the problem which I am facing is the whenever I specify a module of this project as a dependency in some other maven project it doesn't get resolved even though I have the dependency jar in my .m2 local repo.

I get this error "Could not resolve dependencies for project failed to read artifact descriptor".

Can someone help understand and resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't see how the structure and the problem with dependency resolving are connected.

Comment: exactly this is what I am failing to understand @JFabianMeier

Comment: My guess would be that they are totally unrelated and you made some other error.

Comment: The described structure looks reasonable as `parent` and `aggregator` POMs are separate concepts in Maven. Could you please provide the following additional information: 1. **whenever I specify a module of this project as a dependency in some other maven project** - is **some other project** part of the same Maven project or a completely separate one? ---- 2. Please add relevant `parent` and `dependency` section declarations to the question.